# iOS Websocket Library(SocketRocket) gets disconnected at every few seconds

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, websocket, socketrocket

I am working on websocket connection and I am using SocketRocket(https://github.com/square/SocketRocket) library for that, I am got successful in connecting with server, but connection gets disconnected at every few seconds. I dont know why this is happening as I want a persistent connection and Websockets are for that only

Help me if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Did you fix the issue? I am facing the same exact issue. Could you tell me how did you fix it, if you do so ?

Comment: As a work around I used a timer which continuously sends a ping to server at every 20 seconds.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198427/srwebsocket-connection-is-closing-automatically-after-keeping-app-idle-for-somet