# SRWebsocket connection is closing automatically after keeping app idle for sometime in iOS

Tags: ios, websocket, socketrocket

I am using SRWebSocket to open a websocket connection in iOS. But if I am keeping the application idle for sometimes, the connection is closing automatically. After that when I am trying to send any data, the websocket connection is failing.

Is there anyway to keep the websocket connection alive, until I manually disconnect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to ping the server intermittently (In my case, I do this in every 30 seconds), for avoiding to close the connection from the server side.

```
- (void)webSocketDidOpen:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket;
{
    NSLog(@"Websocket Connected");

    // Sending autoping to server
    [self startConnectionCheckTimer];
}

// Checking for WSconnection by Sending Scheduled Ping
- (void)startConnectionCheckTimer {
    if (!_timer) {
        _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0f
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(sendPing:)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];
    }
}

- (void)stopConnectionCheckTimer {
    if ([_timer isValid]) {
        [_timer invalidate];
    }
    _timer = nil;
}

- (void)sendPing:(id)sender
{
    [_webSocket sendPing:nil];
}
```

Where, **_webSocket** is my SRWebSocket object,
       **_timer** is an object of NSTimer.

Answer (score 2):

Web Socket gets disconnected when the app is kept idle or when the app goes in background. You can try using this:
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES

Using this, will disable the provision of iPhone to be idle if your app is running.

Comment: I used this for preventing the websocket connection is closing from client side. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @NobinThomas: If this answer worked for you, then please +1. I will be happy to help if you have any other issues.

Comment: Hi Neha, Unfortunately, I don't have that much reputation to add the points (Showing need minimum 15 points). :( I will add once i gain that privilege. Appreciate your response.

Comment: Also, from the documentation i get to know that, 
You should set this property only if necessary and should be sure to reset it to NO when the need no longer exists. The only apps that should disable the idle timer are mapping apps, games, or programs where the app needs to continue displaying content when user interaction is minimal.
Ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/idleTimerDisabled.
That is why i choose the above option.

Comment: It's also useful for apps that sit in the background checking for push notifications (i.e. Facebook).